# Regex - match character only once - then ignore

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I went through a lot of questions and couldn't solve my problem.

I need to match a number of special characters, but only once.

HTML:

```
 <form class="FillIn Rearrange">
       <input data-correctanswer="ça" type="text">,
       <input data-correctanswer="ça" type="text">
       <input data-correctanswer="vé" type="text">
       <input data-correctanswer="bién" type="text">
</form>
```

This JS currently returns ALL ç, and é, but I need 1 max. of each:

```
 var buttons = '';
        $('.FillIn input').each(function () {
            var corrAns = $(this).attr('data-correctanswer');


            for (var i = 0; i < corrAns.length; i++) {
                if (corrAns[i].match(/[éç]/g)) {
                    buttons += '<button>' + corrAns[i] + '</button>';
                }
            }
        });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyka88/r1en3tnm/5/)

Currently returns ççéé (all occurrences)

Need it to return çé  (one of each).

Need a scalable solution, i.e. .match(/[éçdfga]/g) (or any extra letter)

Comment: I though removing the g would do it, but it doesn't (/[éç]/g --> /[éç]/). Still does a global search

Comment: (guess it is because it considers every 'data-correctanswer' as a separate string)

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear, you want to reduce from `[ça, ça, vé, bién]` to `[ça, vé]` ?

Comment: Please see fiddle -- currently returns çéççç (as inserted buttons). Need to get çé (one of each max.)

Comment: I was just trying to make sure about your intent. So you really mean one of each once.

Comment: Yes, one of each once. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```js
var buttons = '';

function createButtons(lettersToMatch){
    $('.FillIn input').each(function () {
        var corrAns = $(this).attr('data-correctanswer');
        
        for (var i = 0; i < corrAns.length; i++) {
            var match = corrAns[i].match(new RegExp(lettersToMatch));
            if (match) {
                buttons += '<button>' + corrAns[i] + '</button>';
                lettersToMatch = lettersToMatch.replace(match[0], "");
            }
        }
    });
}

//Testing
createButtons("[éèçêïë]");
$("body").append( buttons );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="FillIn Rearrange">
    <input data-correctanswer="çaï" type="text">,
    <input data-correctanswer="ça" type="text">
    <input data-correctanswer="vé" type="text">
    <input data-correctanswer="bién" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: If you put the brackets in the regexp declaration and use only letters in `lettersToMatch`, you can stop early when `lettersToMatch` is empty. You can also return the buttons instead of binding them globally.

Comment: Sir, you're awesome. Accepting as the correct for the extra effort of code snippet. I understand that this line " lettersToMatch = lettersToMatch.replace(match[0], "");" does what I've been missing. But I vaguely understand how it replaces something found with nothing (""). Would you be so kind and comment this line?

Comment: You can read more on how the replace() function works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Simply what it does is finding the first argument in the string and replacing it with the second.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to end the for loop as soon as you get a match, so throw in a break statement:

```
 var buttons = '';
        $('.FillIn input').each(function () {
            var corrAns = $(this).attr('data-correctanswer');


            for (var i = 0; i < corrAns.length; i++) {
                if (corrAns[i].match(/[éç]/g)) {
                    buttons += '<button>' + corrAns[i] + '</button>';
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: That doesn't work. That would stop at first ç encountered. But I need it to keep looking until é is found.

Comment: Oh so you want to stop after at least one é and at least one ç? You could have a separate regex if statement for each, and whenever you get a match, you set a flag for that letter. After the if statements, you check if both flags are true, and if so, break

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that it is actually for many more letters -- [é,è, à, ù,â, ê, î, ô, û] (and more). so I really prefer to avoid separate regexes.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to remember what you have already found and not process it:

```
var buttons = '';
var found   = []; // this remembers what we have already found

$('.FillIn input').each(function () {

    var corrAns = $(this).attr('data-correctanswer');

    for (var i = 0; i < corrAns.length; i++) {

        var m; // hold the match
        if (m = corrAns[i].match(/[éç]/)) {

            // not found yet
            if(found.indexOf(m[0]) == -1) {

                found.push(m[0]) // remember it's been found
                buttons += '<button>' + corrAns[i] + '</button>';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You're awesome too so +1 :). As I was walking home I started of thinking about pushing matched characters to a separate array. And you nailed it.